# asp.net mvc Custom HandleUnauthorizedRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working with asp.net mvc3.

I have a custom AuthorizeAttribute.

I have to override method **HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)**

My source code is as follows.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    switch (unAuthorizedStatus)
    {
        case UnauthorizedStatus.NonAuthenticated:
            // I have a question here.
            break;
        default: base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext); break;
    }
}
```

// I have a question here.

If it fails to user authentication(case UnauthorizedStatus.NonAuthenticated), to return to the previous URL, 
And I want to show the warning window alert in JavaScript(or jquery).

To answer please.

Comment: Answer Myself : filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('message'); history.back();</script>");

Comment: Please tell me if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need to override the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method?

I followed the approach listed here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx. Its so good they wrapped it up into MVC4.

Essentially, you handle the OnAuthorization method only. The rest you leave to the base Attribute. That has the nice feature of automatically routing you to the logon page if you are unauthenticated.

If you really want to auto navigate the user back to the original page, you can override the method as you were originally thinking, but instead send the user to a new action method, and pass the return URL from the HttpContext (referring url I think). You can then show a message to the user in html, and then auto navigate the user back to their original page after a couple of seconds wait via a meta refresh.

Your solution wont work if the end user has JS disabled.